# telerik tabstrip controls are showing up in other tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have 3 telerik tabs:

```
    <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="tabStrip" runat="server" MultiPageID="multiPage" SelectedIndex="0" ClickSelectedTab="true" OnTabClick="tabStrip_TabClick">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Pending Invoices" PageViewID="pendingInvoicesPageView">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Paid Invoices" PageViewID="paidInvoicesPageView">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="My Payment Account" PageViewID="myPaymentAccountPageView">
            </telerik:RadTab>                
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

with 3 page view:

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="multiPage" runat="server"
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="PageView1" runat="server"> 
    </telerik:RadPageView>
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="PageView2" runat="server"> 
    </telerik:RadPageView>
    <telerik:RadPageView ID="PageView3" runat="server"> 
    </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Now, the contents of PageView1 is showing up in PageView2 and PageView3 after I added the below code:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="radAjaxManager" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="tabStrip">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="tabStrip" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="multiPage" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="multiPage">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="tabStrip" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="multiPage" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>            
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Please give me an advise, i'm lost in this telerik control. TIA!

Here's some of the content of RadPageView:

```
    <wac:WebDialogControl Id="WebDialogControl1" Runat="server" Label="" LabelVAlign="top">

        <asp:DataGrid Id="paidInvoiceGrid" Runat="server"  >

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Id" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PaymentDate" HeaderText="Date"  />
                <asp:ButtonColumn DataTextField="InvoiceId" HeaderText="Invoice #"  />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Services For"  />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PaymentAmount" HeaderText="Amount"  />
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="PaidInFullDescription" HeaderText="Payment(s)" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:DataGrid>

    </wac:WebDialogControl>
```

Comment: Can you show me some of Contents of PageView1 , 2 and 3 . And how did you bind this contents ?

Comment: here's some of the controls in RadPageView, asp:DataGrid, asp:Panel, UserControls, tables.

Comment: I've added a code in the question

Comment: telerik sent an answer to that. here's the video link which uses that same code http://screencast.com/t/16dx581Cl2

Answer (score 2):

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="multiPage" runat="server">
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="PageView1" runat="server"> 
  </telerik:RadPageView>
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="PageView2" runat="server"> 
  </telerik:RadPageView>
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="PageView3" runat="server"> 
  </telerik:RadPageView>
</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Should be:

```
 <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="multiPage" runat="server">
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="pendingInvoicesPageView" runat="server"> 
  </telerik:RadPageView>
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="paidInvoicesPageView" runat="server"> 
  </telerik:RadPageView>
  <telerik:RadPageView ID="myPaymentAccountPageView" runat="server"> 
  </telerik:RadPageView>
 </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

You should point to the right RadMultiPage in your RadTabStrip control, which you are doing correctly. However, the PageViewIDs of the PageViews inside RadMultiPage should point to the PageViewIDs of the RadTabStrip.